# Custom date format with jQuery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, validation, datetime-format

How can I specify a custom date formate to be validated with the [Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) for jQuery?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You can create your own custom validation method using the [`addMethod`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage) function. Say you wanted to validate "dd/mm/yyyy":

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "australianDate",
    function(value, element) {
        // put your own logic here, this is just a (crappy) example
        return value.match(/^\d\d?\/\d\d?\/\d\d\d\d$/);
    },
    "Please enter a date in the format dd/mm/yyyy."
);
```

And then on your form add:

```
$('#myForm')
    .validate({
        rules : {
            myDate : {
                australianDate : true
            }
        }
    })
;
```

Comment: @blasteralfred: `// put your own logic here, this is just a (crappy) example`

Comment: can u suggest me a syntax which validates my required format DD-MM-YYYY ?? I am a beginner in jquery .. :)

Comment: Should be noted that you should change `myDate` to the name of the date input field.

Comment: You can replace the example reg-ex with;
return value.match(/^(((((0[1-9])|(1\d)|(2[0-8]))\/((0[1-9])|(1[0-2])))|((31\/((0[13578])|(1[02])))|((29|30)\/((0[1,3-9])|(1[0-2])))))\/((20[0-9][0-9])|(19[0-9][0-9])))|((29\/02\/(19|20)(([02468][048])|([13579][26]))))$/);

This supports leap year checking.
Eg. 
29/02/20014 will FAIL validation
29/02/2016 will PASS validation.

Answer (score 59):

nickf's answer is good, but note that the validation plug-in already includes validators for several other date formats, in the additional-methods.js file. Before you write your own, make sure that someone hasn't already done it.

Comment: setting the rule dateISO: true, validates date in the format yyy-mm-dd

Comment: Great, thanks! There is "dateITA" for "dd/mm/yyyy" format, for example.

Answer (score 22):

I personally use the very good http://www.datejs.com/ library.

Docco here: http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation

You can use the following to get your Australian format and will validate the leap day 29/02/2012 and not 29/02/2011:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("australianDate", function(value, element) { 
    return Date.parseExact(value, "d/M/yyyy");
});

$("#myForm").validate({
   rules : {
      birth_date : { australianDate : true }
   }
});
```

I also use the masked input plugin to standardise the data http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

```
$("#birth_date").mask("99/99/9999");
```

Answer (score 18):

Here is an example for a new validation method that will validate almost any date format, including:

- dd/mm/yy or dd/mm/yyyy
- dd.mm.yy or dd.mm.yyyy
- dd,mm,yy or dd,mm,yyyy
- dd mm yy or dd mm yyyy
- dd-mm-yy or dd-mm-yyyy

Then, when you pass the value to the php you can convert it with [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Here is how to add the method:

```
    $.validator.addMethod("anyDate",
    function(value, element) {
        return value.match(/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-1])[/., -](0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[/., -](19|20)?\d{2}$/);
    },
    "Please enter a date in the format!"
);
```

Then you add the new filter with:

```
$('#myForm')
.validate({
    rules : {
        field: {
            anyDate: true
        }
    }
})
```

;

Comment: and to include `mmm`, I've used slightly modified the regex to `/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-1])[/., -](0?[1-9]|1[0-2]|[a-zA-Z]{3})[/., -](19|20)?\d{2}$/`

Answer (score 13):

Here's a specific code sample which worked for me recently:

```
// Replace the builtin US date validation with UK date validation
$.validator.addMethod(
    "date",
    function ( value, element ) {
        var bits = value.match( /([0-9]+)/gi ), str;
        if ( ! bits )
            return this.optional(element) || false;
        str = bits[ 1 ] + '/' + bits[ 0 ] + '/' + bits[ 2 ];
        return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date( str ));
    },
    "Please enter a date in the format dd/mm/yyyy"
);
```

I should note that this actually replaces the built-in date validation routine, though I couldn't see that this should cause an issue with the current plugin.

I then applied this to the form using:

```
$( '#my_form input.date' ).rules( 'add', { date: true } );
```

Answer (score 6):

This is me combining/modifying previous posts to achieve my desired result:

```
        // Override built-in date validator
        $.validator.addMethod(
            "date",
            function (value, element) {
                //Return            NB: isRequired is not checked at this stage
                return (value=="")? true : isDate(value);
            },
            "* invalid"
        );
```

Add Date validation after your validation config. I.e. after calling the $(form).validate({ ... }) method.

```
        //Add date validation (if applicable)
        $('.date', $(frmPanelBtnId)).each(function () {
            $(this).rules('add', {
                date: true
            });
        });
```

Finally, the main isDate Javascript function modified for UK Date Format

```
//Validates a date input -- http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2011/12/validate-date-    using-jquery.html
function isDate(txtDate) {
    var currVal = txtDate;
    if (currVal == '')
       return false;

  //Declare Regex  
  var rxDatePattern = /^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{4})$/;
  var dtArray = currVal.match(rxDatePattern); // is format OK?

  if (dtArray == null)
      return false;

   //Checks for dd/mm/yyyy format.
   var dtDay = dtArray[1];
   var dtMonth = dtArray[3];
   var dtYear = dtArray[5];

  if (dtMonth < 1 || dtMonth > 12)
      return false;
  else if (dtDay < 1 || dtDay > 31)
      return false;
  else if ((dtMonth == 4 || dtMonth == 6 || dtMonth == 9 || dtMonth == 11) && dtDay == 31)
      return false;
  else if (dtMonth == 2) {
      var isleap = (dtYear % 4 == 0 && (dtYear % 100 != 0 || dtYear % 400 == 0));
      if (dtDay > 29 || (dtDay == 29 && !isleap))
          return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Jon, you have some syntax errors, see below, this worked for me.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

  $.validator.addMethod(
      "australianDate",
      function (value, element) {
        // put your own logic here, this is just a (crappy) example 
        return value.match(/^\d\d?\/\d\d?\/\d\d\d\d$/);
      },
      "Please enter a date in the format dd/mm/yyyy"
    );

  $('#testForm').validate({
    rules: {
      "myDate": {
        australianDate: true
      }
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$.validator.addMethod("mydate", function (value, element) {

        return this.optional(element) || /^(\d{4})(-|\/)(([0-1]{1})([1-2]{1})|([0]{1})([0-9]{1}))(-|\/)(([0-2]{1})([1-9]{1})|([3]{1})([0-1]{1}))/.test(value);

    });
```

you can input like `yyyy-mm-dd` also `yyyy/mm/dd`

but can't judge the the size of the month sometime Feb just 28 or 29 days.

Answer (score 1):

@blasteralfred:

I got following rule validating correct date for me (DD MM YYYY)

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod(
"validDate",
function(value, element) {
    return value.match(/(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) (?:0[1-9]|1[0-2]) (?:19|20\d{2})/);
},
"Please enter a valid date in the format DD MM YYYY"
```

);

For DD/MM/YYYY

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod(
"validDate",
function(value, element) {
    return value.match(/(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(?:19|20\d{2})/);
},
"Please enter a valid date in the format DD/MM/YYYY"
```

);

This will not validate 01 13 2017 and 01/13/2017.

And also does not validate 50 12 2017 and 50/12/2017.

Answer (score 0):

**Is Easy, Example: *Valid for  HTML5 automatic type="date"*.**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/localization/messages_es.js"></script>

$(function () {

        // Overload method default "date" jquery.validate.min.js
        $.validator.addMethod(
            "date",
            function(value, element) {
                var dateReg = /^\d{2}([./-])\d{2}\1\d{4}$/;
                return value.match(dateReg);
            },
            "Invalid date"
        );

     // Form Demo jquery.validate.min.js
     $('#form-datos').validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });

});
```