# Can I simplify/optimise this Jquery code at all?

Tags: jquery, validation, optimization

I've wrote some code that will check two dates - they are split into two day inputs (#enddate-1-dd, #date-1-dd), two month inputs (#enddate-1-mm, #date-1-mm) and two year inputs (#enddate-1, #date-1)

I wanted to check first of all that they're all actually numbers, but then I wanted to check each one to make sure it's in a date format, at the moment it's like this:

```
function validate_form () {

retVal = true; // if the statements below fail, return true

if(retVal == true) {
    // check whether the available hours they've entered are a valid time!
    $(":text").each(function() {
        $this = $(this); // cache the object
        if (isNaN($this.val())) {
            $this.focus();
            $.jGrowl('Please enter a valid date!', { theme: 'smoke' });
            retVal = false; return false;
        }
    });
}

if(retVal == true) {
    $("#date-1-dd").each(function() {
        $this = $(this); // cache the object
        if ($this.val() > 31) {
            $this.focus();
            $.jGrowl('Please enter a valid day, should be no more than 31!', { theme: 'smoke' });
            retVal = false; return false;
        }
    });
}

if(retVal == true) {
    $("#enddate-1-dd").each(function() {
        $this = $(this); // cache the object
        if ($this.val() > 31) {
            $this.focus();
            $.jGrowl('Please enter a valid day, should be no more than 31!', { theme: 'smoke' });
            retVal = false; return false;
        }
    });
}

if(retVal == true) {
    $("#date-1-mm").each(function() {
        $this = $(this); // cache the object
        if ($this.val() > 12) {
            $this.focus();
            $.jGrowl('Please enter a valid month, should be no more than 12!', { theme: 'smoke' });
            retVal = false; return false;
        }
    });
}

if(retVal == true) {
    $("#enddate-1-mm").each(function() {
        $this = $(this); // cache the object
        if ($this.val() > 12) {
            $this.focus();
            $.jGrowl('Please enter a valid month, should be no more than 12!', { theme: 'smoke' });
            retVal = false; return false;
        }
    });
}

if(retVal == true) {
    $("#date-1").each(function() {
        $this = $(this); // cache the object
        if ($this.val() < 1900 || $this.val() > 3000) {
            $this.focus();
            $.jGrowl('Please enter a valid year!', { theme: 'smoke' });
            retVal = false; return false;
        }
    });
}

if(retVal == true) {
    $("#enddate-1").each(function() {
        $this = $(this); // cache the object
        if ($this.val() < 1900 || $this.val() > 3000) {
            $this.focus();
            $.jGrowl('Please enter a valid year!', { theme: 'smoke' });
            retVal = false; return false;
        }
    });
}

return retVal; // return either true or false, depending on what happened up there! ^
```

}

Sorry if it seems like I'm asking a silly question, as my code is working okay, I just think it's a rubbish way of doing it, with loads of repetition, but I can't really think of any way of doing it more efficiently?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function validate_form_checks() {
    var error;
    // check whether the available hours they've entered are a valid time!
    $(':text').each(function() {
        if(isNaN($(this).val())) {
            $(this).focus();
            error = 'Please enter a valid date!';
            return false;
        }
    });
    if(error)
        return error;
    $('#date-1-dd, #enddate-1-dd').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() > 31) {
            $(this).focus();
            error = 'Please enter a valid day, should be no more than 31!';
            return false;
        }
    });
    if(error)
        return error;
    $('#date-1-mm, #enddate-1-mm').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() > 12) {
            $(this).focus();
            error = 'Please enter a valid month, should be no more than 12!';
            return false;
        }
    });
    if(error)
        return error;
    $('#date-1, #enddate-1').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() < 1900 || $(this).val() > 3000) {
            $(this).focus();
            error = 'Please enter a valid year!';
            return false;
        }
    });
    if(error)
        return error;
    return true;
}

function validate_form() {
    var result = validate_form_checks();
    if(result === true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        $.jGrowl(result, { theme: 'smoke' });
        return false;
    }
}
```

Of course, validation that provides feedback on *all* the errors in a form instead of just the first one is kind of, y'know, better.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance you could create a function from those identical sections and just call it as needed.  [You shouldn't repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Here is a [blog post](http://calisza.wordpress.com/2009/03/09/how-to-validate-date-of-birth-with-jquery/) about validating dates that may be enlightening.  And here's an SO answer that gives a [jQuery plugin answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511439/custom-date-format-with-jquery-validation-plugin) to date validation.

Comment: What does SO mean in this context? I've seen it before today!

Comment: StackOverflow.  The site you're on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here:

```
function validate_form() {
return retVal = !0, retVal == 1 && $(":text")
    .each(function () {
    return $this = $(this), isNaN($this.val()) ? ($this.focus(), $.jGrowl("Please enter a valid date!", {
        theme: "smoke"
    }), retVal = !1, !1) : void 0
}), retVal == 1 && $("#date-1-dd")
    .each(function () {
    return $this = $(this), $this.val() > 31 ? ($this.focus(), $.jGrowl("Please enter a valid day, should be no more than 31!", {
        theme: "smoke"
    }), retVal = !1, !1) : void 0
}), retVal == 1 && $("#enddate-1-dd")
    .each(function () {
    return $this = $(this), $this.val() > 31 ? ($this.focus(), $.jGrowl("Please enter a valid day, should be no more than 31!", {
        theme: "smoke"
    }), retVal = !1, !1) : void 0
}), retVal == 1 && $("#date-1-mm")
    .each(function () {
    return $this = $(this), $this.val() > 12 ? ($this.focus(), $.jGrowl("Please enter a valid month, should be no more than 12!", {
        theme: "smoke"
    }), retVal = !1, !1) : void 0
}), retVal == 1 && $("#enddate-1-mm")
    .each(function () {
    return $this = $(this), $this.val() > 12 ? ($this.focus(), $.jGrowl("Please enter a valid month, should be no more than 12!", {
        theme: "smoke"
    }), retVal = !1, !1) : void 0
}), retVal == 1 && $("#date-1")
    .each(function () {
    return $this = $(this), 1900 > $this.val() || $this.val() > 3e3 ? ($this.focus(), $.jGrowl("Please enter a valid year!", {
        theme: "smoke"
    }), retVal = !1, !1) : void 0
}), retVal == 1 && $("#enddate-1")
    .each(function () {
    return $this = $(this), 1900 > $this.val() || $this.val() > 3e3 ? ($this.focus(), $.jGrowl("Please enter a valid year!", {
        theme: "smoke"
    }), retVal = !1, !1) : void 0
}), retVal
}
```