# Determing the type of the return value

Tags: javascript

I get a return value from a function which is always string. i used `typeof(obj)` which turns out to be `string` always.

```
Date.functionName=Date.prototype.functionName=function(dataObj) {
        //The dataObj is always string. 
            // How can i differentiate between the values... 
};
```

I have three things coming as strings..

1. Date
2. String...
3. Integer values...

All the three are of type `string`.

1. How can i differentiate these three values.
2. Is it correct to use Date.mycustomfunction... or should i use some
   other class...

Comment: Why are they strings? You should pass actual numbers.

Comment: Agree. Just pass the actual values, not converted to a string and differentiate using typeof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [isNaN](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) to check if it's an integer or not.  And there's some interesting ideas [here](http://www.codetoad.com/forum/17_10053.asp) for isDate type of functionality.  Also some answers here may help:  [How can I determine whether a given string represents a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880615/isdate-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

I was unsure about the date format used so you will need to add in the appropriate regular expression yourself:

```
var integer = null ;

if(   isNaN(  ( integer = parseInt(string) )  )  ===   false   ) ... //!! integer String values
else {

    if(  ( /*regular expression for your date format*/ ).test(string)  ===  true  ) //!! date String values
    else //!! all other String values

}
```

Btw, it is considered bad practice to add to native `Objects` in JavaScript because it is not as reliable as writing new `Objects`.