# Sorting table rows according to table header column using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have something like this

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>S.L.</th>
            <th>name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Ronaldo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Messi</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Ribery</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Bale</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What i want is to sort the `<tr>` of `<tbody>` when clicked `th` in ascending and descending order alternatively in according to the following `th` clicked.

1. so if some one clicks the `S.L` `th` then it shows the table rows in
   descending and then ascending order alternatively at every click.
2. When clicked `Name` `th` it should show the names in descending
   order and then ascending order without change in their respective
   `S.L`

here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2seK/)

Comment: [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kgondra/qGf45/)... [The original question here.](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37632/how-should-i-sort-an-html-table-with-javascript-in-a-more-efficient-manner)

Comment: @Bhavik your "Working Fiddle" does not work.

Comment: @RyanBrewer [here you go, my "Working Fiddle" has started working](http://jsfiddle.net/qGf45/13/)

Comment: can u implement it in jquery using my solution coz i am little weak in javascript @Bhavik

Comment: @user3508453 ***[`here you go`](http://jsfiddle.net/a2seK/5/)***

Comment: i got it but my curiosity is how u did it ? canu  explain in an answer ? coz i did not understood the functions u used. @Bhavik

Comment: Updated it with few comments.. http://jsfiddle.net/a2seK/6/

Comment: but if we dont know the second parameter in your function `sort_table` i.e the `nth child` how do we do it ? @Bhavik

Comment: Do any of the solutions use memoization, that is, do they store their results so they can be used again?  Thinking about it a little harder, this might require a full page refresh if table rows are added/edited/deleted.  Another idea is to create the necessary additional data structure(s) and pre-sort the data.

Answer (score 42):

You might want to see this page: 
http://blog.niklasottosson.com/?p=1914

I guess you can go something like this:

DEMO:http://jsfiddle.net/g9eL6768/2/

HTML:

```
 <table id="mytable"><thead>
  <tr>
     <th id="sl">S.L.</th>
     <th id="nm">name</th>
  </tr>
   ....
```

JS:

```
//  sortTable(f,n)
//  f : 1 ascending order, -1 descending order
//  n : n-th child(<td>) of <tr>
function sortTable(f,n){
    var rows = $('#mytable tbody  tr').get();

    rows.sort(function(a, b) {

        var A = getVal(a);
        var B = getVal(b);

        if(A < B) {
            return -1*f;
        }
        if(A > B) {
            return 1*f;
        }
        return 0;
    });

    function getVal(elm){
        var v = $(elm).children('td').eq(n).text().toUpperCase();
        if($.isNumeric(v)){
            v = parseInt(v,10);
        }
        return v;
    }

    $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
        $('#mytable').children('tbody').append(row);
    });
}
var f_sl = 1; // flag to toggle the sorting order
var f_nm = 1; // flag to toggle the sorting order
$("#sl").click(function(){
    f_sl *= -1; // toggle the sorting order
    var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
    sortTable(f_sl,n);
});
$("#nm").click(function(){
    f_nm *= -1; // toggle the sorting order
    var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
    sortTable(f_nm,n);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: why have u used `sortTable(variable,0)` & `sortTable(variable,1)`?

Comment: @user3508453, I appended explanation of parameter of `sortTable` on my answer above. On the `sortTable(f,n)`  ,  `f` : 1 ascending order, -1 descending order , and  `n` : n-th child(<td>) of <tr>

Comment: if we are unknown about nth child how do we get the `n` of `td` ? @naota

Comment: @user3508453, thanks. Could you explain more about "unknown about nth"?  What kind of case do you consider?

Comment: i consider adding `table headers` unknown numbers of time as done in `google forms` then i dont know how many table headers my user creates.....

Comment: U almost solved it.
But if i have `SL` in digits of tens or thousands or even more its causing a problem and mistake while ordering it.
Suppose s.l are in range of 1-1000 then it would order it incorrectly.

Comment: Sorry to necro this, but there is a problem when sorting a numeric column as shown in this updated fiddle >  http://jsfiddle.net/a2seK/567/   <

Comment: @SanuelJackson: Thank you for pointing me out the issue. I edited my code above. In the new code, each value is checked if it is Numeric or not.

Comment: Thanks for great solution. It´s works well not only on tables, but on "tables makes via divs". +1

Comment: great solution ji

Comment: numbers with decimal gives wrong sorting order. example(for me): 8.67, 8.31, 8.59 –
removing
                if($.isNumeric(v)){
                    v = parseInt(v,10);
                }
fixed decimal sorting issue

Answer (score 11):

use Javascript **sort()** function

```js
var $tbody = $('table tbody');
$tbody.find('tr').sort(function(a,b){ 
    var tda = $(a).find('td:eq(1)').text(); // can replace 1 with the column you want to sort on
    var tdb = $(b).find('td:eq(1)').text(); // this will sort on the second column
            // if a < b return 1
    return tda < tdb ? 1 
           // else if a > b return -1
           : tda > tdb ? -1 
           // else they are equal - return 0    
           : 0;           
}).appendTo($tbody);
```

If you want ascending you just have to reverse the > and <

Change the logic accordingly for you.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sharmapattar/8kp2vjm3/)

Comment: This one also fails to sort numerically properly >  http://jsfiddle.net/8kp2vjm3/59/

Comment: To make is work numerically just update the code tda < tdb to +tda< +tdb and it will work > See updated fiddle >> http://jsfiddle.net/vishal_vash/8kp2vjm3/131/

Comment: I like this one. Solve my problem for decimal figures. I made it ascending and descending by changing the error. thanks SharmaPattar

Answer (score 9):

Offering an interactive sort handling multiple columns is nothing trivial.

Unless you want to write a good amount of code handling logic for multiple row clicks, editing and refreshing page content, managing sort algorithms for large tables… then you really are better off adopting a plug-in.

[tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/), (with updates by Mottie) is my favorite. It’s easy to get going and very customizable. Just add the class `tablesorter` to the table you want to sort, then invoke the tablesorter plugin in a document load event:

```
$(function(){
    $("#myTable").tablesorter();
});
```

You can browse [the documentation](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) to learn about advanced features.

Comment: This plugin works well unless the table has been modified at runtime. It doesn't take into account changes made to the cell contents. Even running .tablesorter() a second time after modification, it fails to see the new data.

Comment: where would that function() call go? It's not obvious.

Answer (score 7):

I think this might help you:
Here is the [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aung48vm/):

And here is the code:

```js
var stIsIE = /*@cc_on!@*/ false;
sorttable = {
  init: function() {
    if (arguments.callee.done) return;
    arguments.callee.done = true;
    if (_timer) clearInterval(_timer);
    if (!document.createElement || !document.getElementsByTagName) return;
    sorttable.DATE_RE = /^(\d\d?)[\/\.-](\d\d?)[\/\.-]((\d\d)?\d\d)$/;
    forEach(document.getElementsByTagName('table'), function(table) {
      if (table.className.search(/\bsortable\b/) != -1) {
        sorttable.makeSortable(table);
      }
    });
  },
  makeSortable: function(table) {
    if (table.getElementsByTagName('thead').length == 0) {
      the = document.createElement('thead');
      the.appendChild(table.rows[0]);
      table.insertBefore(the, table.firstChild);
    }
    if (table.tHead == null) table.tHead = table.getElementsByTagName('thead')[0];
    if (table.tHead.rows.length != 1) return;
    sortbottomrows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
      if (table.rows[i].className.search(/\bsortbottom\b/) != -1) {
        sortbottomrows[sortbottomrows.length] = table.rows[i];
      }
    }
    if (sortbottomrows) {
      if (table.tFoot == null) {
        tfo = document.createElement('tfoot');
        table.appendChild(tfo);
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < sortbottomrows.length; i++) {
        tfo.appendChild(sortbottomrows[i]);
      }
      delete sortbottomrows;
    }
    headrow = table.tHead.rows[0].cells;
    for (var i = 0; i < headrow.length; i++) {
      if (!headrow[i].className.match(/\bsorttable_nosort\b/)) {
        mtch = headrow[i].className.match(/\bsorttable_([a-z0-9]+)\b/);
        if (mtch) {
          override = mtch[1];
        }
        if (mtch && typeof sorttable["sort_" + override] == 'function') {
          headrow[i].sorttable_sortfunction = sorttable["sort_" + override];
        } else {
          headrow[i].sorttable_sortfunction = sorttable.guessType(table, i);
        }
        headrow[i].sorttable_columnindex = i;
        headrow[i].sorttable_tbody = table.tBodies[0];
        dean_addEvent(headrow[i], "click", sorttable.innerSortFunction = function(e) {

          if (this.className.search(/\bsorttable_sorted\b/) != -1) {
            sorttable.reverse(this.sorttable_tbody);
            this.className = this.className.replace('sorttable_sorted',
              'sorttable_sorted_reverse');
            this.removeChild(document.getElementById('sorttable_sortfwdind'));
            sortrevind = document.createElement('span');
            sortrevind.id = "sorttable_sortrevind";
            sortrevind.innerHTML = stIsIE ? '&nbsp<font face="webdings">5</font>' : '&nbsp;&#x25B4;';
            this.appendChild(sortrevind);
            return;
          }
          if (this.className.search(/\bsorttable_sorted_reverse\b/) != -1) {
            sorttable.reverse(this.sorttable_tbody);
            this.className = this.className.replace('sorttable_sorted_reverse',
              'sorttable_sorted');
            this.removeChild(document.getElementById('sorttable_sortrevind'));
            sortfwdind = document.createElement('span');
            sortfwdind.id = "sorttable_sortfwdind";
            sortfwdind.innerHTML = stIsIE ? '&nbsp<font face="webdings">6</font>' : '&nbsp;&#x25BE;';
            this.appendChild(sortfwdind);
            return;
          }
          theadrow = this.parentNode;
          forEach(theadrow.childNodes, function(cell) {
            if (cell.nodeType == 1) {
              cell.className = cell.className.replace('sorttable_sorted_reverse', '');
              cell.className = cell.className.replace('sorttable_sorted', '');
            }
          });
          sortfwdind = document.getElementById('sorttable_sortfwdind');
          if (sortfwdind) {
            sortfwdind.parentNode.removeChild(sortfwdind);
          }
          sortrevind = document.getElementById('sorttable_sortrevind');
          if (sortrevind) {
            sortrevind.parentNode.removeChild(sortrevind);
          }

          this.className += ' sorttable_sorted';
          sortfwdind = document.createElement('span');
          sortfwdind.id = "sorttable_sortfwdind";
          sortfwdind.innerHTML = stIsIE ? '&nbsp<font face="webdings">6</font>' : '&nbsp;&#x25BE;';
          this.appendChild(sortfwdind);
          row_array = [];
          col = this.sorttable_columnindex;
          rows = this.sorttable_tbody.rows;
          for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
            row_array[row_array.length] = [sorttable.getInnerText(rows[j].cells[col]), rows[j]];
          }
          row_array.sort(this.sorttable_sortfunction);
          tb = this.sorttable_tbody;
          for (var j = 0; j < row_array.length; j++) {
            tb.appendChild(row_array[j][1]);
          }
          delete row_array;
        });
      }
    }
  },

  guessType: function(table, column) {
    sortfn = sorttable.sort_alpha;
    for (var i = 0; i < table.tBodies[0].rows.length; i++) {
      text = sorttable.getInnerText(table.tBodies[0].rows[i].cells[column]);
      if (text != '') {
        if (text.match(/^-?[£$¤]?[\d,.]+%?$/)) {
          return sorttable.sort_numeric;
        }
        possdate = text.match(sorttable.DATE_RE)
        if (possdate) {
          first = parseInt(possdate[1]);
          second = parseInt(possdate[2]);
          if (first > 12) {
            return sorttable.sort_ddmm;
          } else if (second > 12) {
            return sorttable.sort_mmdd;
          } else {
            sortfn = sorttable.sort_ddmm;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return sortfn;
  },
  getInnerText: function(node) {
    if (!node) return "";
    hasInputs = (typeof node.getElementsByTagName == 'function') &&
      node.getElementsByTagName('input').length;
    if (node.getAttribute("sorttable_customkey") != null) {
      return node.getAttribute("sorttable_customkey");
    } else if (typeof node.textContent != 'undefined' && !hasInputs) {
      return node.textContent.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    } else if (typeof node.innerText != 'undefined' && !hasInputs) {
      return node.innerText.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    } else if (typeof node.text != 'undefined' && !hasInputs) {
      return node.text.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    } else {
      switch (node.nodeType) {
        case 3:
          if (node.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'input') {
            return node.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
          }
        case 4:
          return node.nodeValue.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
          break;
        case 1:
        case 11:
          var innerText = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
            innerText += sorttable.getInnerText(node.childNodes[i]);
          }
          return innerText.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
          break;
        default:
          return '';
      }
    }
  },
  reverse: function(tbody) {
    // reverse the rows in a tbody
    newrows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < tbody.rows.length; i++) {
      newrows[newrows.length] = tbody.rows[i];
    }
    for (var i = newrows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      tbody.appendChild(newrows[i]);
    }
    delete newrows;
  },
  sort_numeric: function(a, b) {
    aa = parseFloat(a[0].replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, ''));
    if (isNaN(aa)) aa = 0;
    bb = parseFloat(b[0].replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, ''));
    if (isNaN(bb)) bb = 0;
    return aa - bb;
  },
  sort_alpha: function(a, b) {
    if (a[0] == b[0]) return 0;
    if (a[0] < b[0]) return -1;
    return 1;
  },
  sort_ddmm: function(a, b) {
    mtch = a[0].match(sorttable.DATE_RE);
    y = mtch[3];
    m = mtch[2];
    d = mtch[1];
    if (m.length == 1) m = '0' + m;
    if (d.length == 1) d = '0' + d;
    dt1 = y + m + d;
    mtch = b[0].match(sorttable.DATE_RE);
    y = mtch[3];
    m = mtch[2];
    d = mtch[1];
    if (m.length == 1) m = '0' + m;
    if (d.length == 1) d = '0' + d;
    dt2 = y + m + d;
    if (dt1 == dt2) return 0;
    if (dt1 < dt2) return -1;
    return 1;
  },
  sort_mmdd: function(a, b) {
    mtch = a[0].match(sorttable.DATE_RE);
    y = mtch[3];
    d = mtch[2];
    m = mtch[1];
    if (m.length == 1) m = '0' + m;
    if (d.length == 1) d = '0' + d;
    dt1 = y + m + d;
    mtch = b[0].match(sorttable.DATE_RE);
    y = mtch[3];
    d = mtch[2];
    m = mtch[1];
    if (m.length == 1) m = '0' + m;
    if (d.length == 1) d = '0' + d;
    dt2 = y + m + d;
    if (dt1 == dt2) return 0;
    if (dt1 < dt2) return -1;
    return 1;
  },
  shaker_sort: function(list, comp_func) {
    var b = 0;
    var t = list.length - 1;
    var swap = true;
    while (swap) {
      swap = false;
      for (var i = b; i < t; ++i) {
        if (comp_func(list[i], list[i + 1]) > 0) {
          var q = list[i];
          list[i] = list[i + 1];
          list[i + 1] = q;
          swap = true;
        }
      }
      t--;

      if (!swap) break;

      for (var i = t; i > b; --i) {
        if (comp_func(list[i], list[i - 1]) < 0) {
          var q = list[i];
          list[i] = list[i - 1];
          list[i - 1] = q;
          swap = true;
        }
      }
      b++;

    }
  }
}
if (document.addEventListener) {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", sorttable.init, false);
}
/* for Internet Explorer */
/*@cc_on @*/
/*@if (@_win32)
    document.write("<script id=__ie_onload defer src=javascript:void(0)><\/script>");
    var script = document.getElementById("__ie_onload");
    script.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == "complete") {
            sorttable.init(); // call the onload handler
        }
    };
/*@end @*/
/* for Safari */
if (/WebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) { // sniff
  var _timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (/loaded|complete/.test(document.readyState)) {
      sorttable.init(); // call the onload handler
    }
  }, 10);
}
/* for other browsers */
window.onload = sorttable.init;

function dean_addEvent(element, type, handler) {
  if (element.addEventListener) {
    element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
  } else {
    if (!handler.$$guid) handler.$$guid = dean_addEvent.guid++;
    if (!element.events) element.events = {};
    var handlers = element.events[type];
    if (!handlers) {
      handlers = element.events[type] = {};
      if (element["on" + type]) {
        handlers[0] = element["on" + type];
      }
    }
    handlers[handler.$$guid] = handler;
    element["on" + type] = handleEvent;
  }
};
dean_addEvent.guid = 1;

function removeEvent(element, type, handler) {
  if (element.removeEventListener) {
    element.removeEventListener(type, handler, false);
  } else {
    if (element.events && element.events[type]) {
      delete element.events[type][handler.$$guid];
    }
  }
};

function handleEvent(event) {
  var returnValue = true;
  event = event || fixEvent(((this.ownerDocument || this.document || this).parentWindow || window).event);
  var handlers = this.events[event.type];
  for (var i in handlers) {
    this.$$handleEvent = handlers[i];
    if (this.$$handleEvent(event) === false) {
      returnValue = false;
    }
  }
  return returnValue;
};

function fixEvent(event) {
  event.preventDefault = fixEvent.preventDefault;
  event.stopPropagation = fixEvent.stopPropagation;
  return event;
};
fixEvent.preventDefault = function() {
  this.returnValue = false;
};
fixEvent.stopPropagation = function() {
  this.cancelBubble = true;
}
if (!Array.forEach) {
  Array.forEach = function(array, block, context) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      block.call(context, array[i], i, array);
    }
  };
}
Function.prototype.forEach = function(object, block, context) {
  for (var key in object) {
    if (typeof this.prototype[key] == "undefined") {
      block.call(context, object[key], key, object);
    }
  }
};
String.forEach = function(string, block, context) {
  Array.forEach(string.split(""), function(chr, index) {
    block.call(context, chr, index, string);
  });
};
var forEach = function(object, block, context) {
  if (object) {
    var resolve = Object;
    if (object instanceof Function) {
      resolve = Function;
    } else if (object.forEach instanceof Function) {
      object.forEach(block, context);
      return;
    } else if (typeof object == "string") {
      resolve = String;
    } else if (typeof object.length == "number") {
      resolve = Array;
    }
    resolve.forEach(object, block, context);
  }
}
```

```css
table.sortable thead {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #666666;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<table class="sortable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>S.L.</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>Goal</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Ronaldo</td>
      <td>120</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Messi</td>
      <td>66</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Ribery</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Bale</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS is used here without any other JQuery Plugin.

Comment: The js code looks silimar with https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js. For how to use it, visit https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery DataTables plugin for applying column sorting in desired way.

[Column Sorting using DataTable](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multi_col_sort.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a function to work within a library for a client, and have been having a lot of trouble keeping the UI responsive during the sorts (even with only a few hundred results).

The function has to resort the entire table each AJAX pagination, as new data may require injection further up. This is what I had so far:

- jQuery library required.
- `table` is the ID of the table being sorted.
- The table attributes `sort-attribute`, `sort-direction` and the column attribute `column` are all pre-set.

Using some of the details above I managed to improve performance a bit.

```
function sorttable(table) {
    var context = $('#' + table), tbody = $('#' + table + ' tbody'), sortfield = $(context).data('sort-attribute'), c, dir = $(context).data('sort-direction'), index = $(context).find('thead th[data-column="' + sortfield + '"]').index();
    if (!sortfield) {
        sortfield = $(context).data('id-attribute');
    };
    switch (dir) {
        case "asc":
            tbody.find('tr').sort(function (a, b) {
                var sortvala = parseFloat($(a).find('td:eq(' + index + ')').text());
                var sortvalb = parseFloat($(b).find('td:eq(' + index + ')').text());
                // if a < b return 1
                return sortvala < sortvalb ? 1
                       // else if a > b return -1
                       : sortvala > sortvalb ? -1
                       // else they are equal - return 0    
                       : 0;
            }).appendTo(tbody);
            break;
        case "desc":
        default:
            tbody.find('tr').sort(function (a, b) {
                var sortvala = parseFloat($(a).find('td:eq(' + index + ')').text());
                var sortvalb = parseFloat($(b).find('td:eq(' + index + ')').text());
                // if a < b return 1
                return sortvala > sortvalb ? 1
                       // else if a > b return -1
                       : sortvala < sortvalb ? -1
                       // else they are equal - return 0    
                       : 0;
            }).appendTo(tbody);
        break;
  }
```

In principle the code works perfectly, but it's painfully slow... are there any ways to improve performance?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var TableIDvalue = "myTable";
var TableLastSortedColumn = -1;

function SortTable() {
  var sortColumn = parseInt(arguments[0]);
  var type = arguments.length > 1 ? arguments[1] : 'T';
  var dateformat = arguments.length > 2 ? arguments[2] : '';
  var table = document.getElementById(TableIDvalue);
  var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
  var rows = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  var arrayOfRows = new Array();

  type = type.toUpperCase();

  dateformat = dateformat.toLowerCase();

  for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
    arrayOfRows[i] = new Object;
    arrayOfRows[i].oldIndex = i;
    var celltext = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[sortColumn].innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "");
    if (type == 'D') {
      arrayOfRows[i].value = GetDateSortingKey(dateformat, celltext);
    } else {
      var re = type == "N" ? /[^\.\-\+\d]/g : /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g;
      arrayOfRows[i].value = celltext.replace(re, "").substr(0, 25).toLowerCase();
    }
  }

  if (sortColumn == TableLastSortedColumn) {
    arrayOfRows.reverse();
  } else {
    TableLastSortedColumn = sortColumn;
    switch (type) {
      case "N":
        arrayOfRows.sort(CompareRowOfNumbers);
        break;
      case "D":
        arrayOfRows.sort(CompareRowOfNumbers);
        break;
      default:
        arrayOfRows.sort(CompareRowOfText);
    }
  }
  var newTableBody = document.createElement("tbody");

  for (var i = 0, len = arrayOfRows.length; i < len; i++) {
    newTableBody.appendChild(rows[arrayOfRows[i].oldIndex].cloneNode(true));
  }
  table.replaceChild(newTableBody, tbody);
}

function CompareRowOfText(a, b) {
  var aval = a.value;
  var bval = b.value;
  return (aval == bval ? 0 : (aval > bval ? 1 : -1));
}

function deleteRow(i) {
  document.getElementById('myTable').deleteRow(i)
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input type="button" onclick="javascript: SortTable(0, 'T');" value="SORT" /></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Shaa</td>
      <td>ABC</td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cnubha</td>
      <td>XYZ</td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fine</td>
      <td>MNO</td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Amit</td>
      <td>PQR</td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sultan</td>
      <td>FGH</td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>UST</td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)" /></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found @naota's solution useful, and extended it to use dates as well

```
//taken from StackOverflow:
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880615/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-given-string-represents-a-date
function isDate(val) {
    var d = new Date(val);
    return !isNaN(d.valueOf());
}

var getVal = function(elm, n){
  var v = $(elm).children('td').eq(n).text().toUpperCase();
  if($.isNumeric(v)){
    v = parseFloat(v,10);
    return v;
  }
  if (isDate(v)) {
    v = new Date(v);
    return v;
  }
  return v;
}
```