# Insert a table row alphabetically ordered in the table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, insert

I have a table which is alphabetically ordered by name (using PHP mysql), now I would like to insert a new row at the correct position in the table without doing a new request to the server. Is there any way to go through the table checking every name and insert the new row at the correct position using jQuery/Javascript?

Comment: Can you provided some code of what you are doing?  Also what have you tried so far?

Comment: see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033294/sorting-table-rows-according-to-table-header-column-using-javascript-or-jquery)
Hope this helps.

Comment: Got it.. Thanks to Mackan and extempl ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also insert it in the end (or anywhere), and then re-sort the entire table using js/jquery:

```
var table  = $('table'),
    rows   = $('tr', table);

$('#sortIt').click(function () {
    rows.sort(function(a, b) {
        var keyA = $('td',a).text();
        var keyB = $('td',b).text();
        return (keyA > keyB) ? 1 : 0;
    }); 
    rows.each(function(index, row) {
        table.append(row);
    });
});
```

Example [here at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8uvr3zbt/2/).

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways, this is just the one of them using jquery:

let's set your new name and new row el

```
var newName = 'YourNewName'
var newRow = $('<tr>') // created new row element with cells
```

get list of names, add newName and sort them; let's say your name column is 2

```
var names = $('td:nth-child(2)').map(function () {return $(this).text()})
names.push(newName)
var sorted = names.sort()
```

getting position of added name

```
var newNamePos = sorted.indexOf(newName)
```

inserting new row to found position

```
$('tr:nth-child(' + (newNamePos + 1) + ')').before(newRow)
```