# How to insert a row in a jQuery sorted table?

Tags: jquery

I'm building a small project as a learning exercise. In it I need to insert a row into a table containing rows of (made up) foods in alphabetical order. Following the procedure in [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771428/insert-a-table-row-alphabetically-ordered-in-the-table) of inserting a row in a sorted table I created this function:

```
    function makeNewRow(food) {
        max = max + 1;
        newFood = food.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + food.substr(1).toLowerCase();
        newRow = "<tr data-foodid=" + max + "><td>" + newFood + "</td></tr>";
        names = $("#ready_foods tr td:first-child").map(function () {return $(this).text();}); 
        names.push(newFood);
        sorted = names.sort();
        newNamePos = sorted.index(newFood); //this line fails
        $('#ready_foods tr td:first-child(' + (newNamePos + 1) + ')').before(newRow);
...
```

In debug I can see that `sorted` is an Object and contains properties of increasing integers of the form, e.g., `0: Amet`. My test work `Greens` shows as object # 9. But the script fails when it comes to determining just that.

How, then, do I get the `newNamePos` to insert `newRow`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.get()` with `.map()` to get the values of `td` in array . Then , use `indexOf` the value which you need to insert and using this index insert your row . Also, added some condition for the length of tr (empty table).

***Demo Code :***

```js
var table = $('table'),
  rows = $('tr', table);
var max = rows.length - 1;

function makeNewRow(food) {
  max = max + 1;
  newFood = food.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + food.substr(1).toLowerCase() + " " + max; //added here max for demo
  newRow = "<tr data-foodid=" + max + "><td>" + newFood + "</td></tr>";
  var names = $("#ready_foods tr > td:first-child").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get(); // to get array
  names.push(newFood);
  sorted = names.sort();
  newNamePos = sorted.indexOf(newFood);
  //if there is no row .. 
  if ($("#ready_foods tr").length > newNamePos) {
    $('tr:nth-child(' + (newNamePos + 1) + ')').before(newRow);
  } else {
    $("#ready_foods").append(newRow)
  }

}
```

```css
#ready_foods tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="makeNewRow('Pizza')">Click Pizza</button>
<button onclick="makeNewRow('Burger')">Click Burger</button>
<button onclick="makeNewRow('Chips')">Chips</button>
<table id="ready_foods">
</table>
```

Comment: I'll check this out. When I first tried the method on which I based my code I got `indexOf is not a function`. Wouldn't that be true with your code?

Comment: @geoB No, because i have use `.get()` this will return array and `indexOf` works with array  . For more info check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: I replaced my code with yours and 'Voila!', I have a properly inserted & sorted table. Many thanks.