# How to change date format in JS

Tags: javascript, date

I found a solution to transform a date like: 
Thu Sep 04 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)
to a format french 04/09/2014

How can i achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10119138/1815058

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by using the Date object and its functions:

```
function zerofy(number){
    if(number < 10)
        number = "0" + number;

    return number;
}

var date = new Date("Thu Sep 04 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)");

var day = zerofy(date.getDate());
var month = zerofy(date.getMonth());
var year = date.getFullYear();

var result = day + "/" + month + "/" + year

console.log(result);
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/ttten5eo/1/)

I would recommend going over [this document from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for these kind of problems.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, are there a way to determinate if the string receive is type of date?

Comment: @user1898765 Refer [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11249683/586051) for that problem. Please mark this answer as accepted if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a basic one-liner would help?

```
function formatDate(date){
    return [('0'+date.getDate()).slice(-2),('0'+date.getMonth()).slice(-2),date.getFullYear()].join('/');
}
```