# How to invalid 00/00/0000 date in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, date, datepicker

I am using jQuery Validation Plugin. I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511439/custom-date-format-with-jquery-validation-plugin/511471#511471) to validate my dates using this plugin. It is working but there is a problem. It is accepting 00/00/0000 date as well. How can I invalid this date as well by modifying following function.

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "australianDate",
    function(value, element) {
        return value.match(/^\d\d?\/\d\d?\/\d\d\d\d$/);
    },
    "Please enter a date in the format dd/mm/yyyy"
);
```

Comment: First you need to decide what the valid dates should be. For example, is `11/11/1111` valid? How about `01/01/0001`. How about `31/04/2010`? It's quite hard to validate dates using only regular expressions. The regexp above captures *most* of the problems and allows a relatively sane date into the system. If you need more robust validation, you should write something that actually tries to parse the date taking into account the semantics of date, month and year and decide whether it's valid or not. Regexps can only go so far.

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim: Yes you are right but for now I just want to invalid a date with all zeros (00/00/0000). Thanks for your concern..

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim is right, different decision is causing different solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you can try this, perhaps it can works :)

```
function(value, element) {
        if (!value.match(/^00\/00\/0000$/)) return value;        
}
```

Comment: This still won't tell you if the date is valid or not. In fact, it will be valid if the input is anything but `00/00/0000`, not so great for date validation.

Answer (score 3):

you can try:

```
function(value, element){
    return /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/.test(value) &&
        !isNaN(+new Date(value.split('/').reverse().join('/')));
}
```

Comment: I will use it instead of `return value.match(/^\d\d?\/\d\d?\/\d\d\d\d$/);` in function in my question ???

Comment: Will `Date()` constructor accept the date in Australian format, `dd/mm/yyy` ?

Comment: @cwolves Us damn Aussies :P BTW, I meant `yyyy` above :)

Comment: Also, doesn't `+` invoke `getTime()`, and it returns `0` for an invalid time, or have I stuffed something up? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eghc9/).

Comment: @Awan - yes, this is in place of your function

Comment: @alex - you stuffed something up.  You're doing `new Date(0.006030453791647822)` in that fiddle, thus zero.  invalid dates return `NaN`.  Try `'400/33/2010'`

Comment: @cwolves Wow, forgetting to quote a string is embarrassing! +1 for showing me the way :)

Comment: Also, your regex is a little different in meaning to the OP's. Yours will only accept 2 digits for month and day, and the OP's will accept 1 or 2.

Answer (score 3):

This will ensure the data is in correct format and is also a valid date.

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "australianDate",
    function(value, element) {
        var tokens =  value.match(/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})/);

        if (tokens == null) {
            return false;
        }

        var date = new Date(tokens[3], --tokens[2], tokens[1]);

        return ! isNaN(date.getTime());

    },
    "Please enter a valid date in the format dd/mm/yyyy"
);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `new Date(tokens[2], tokens[1], tokens[0])`?

Comment: @James `tokens[0]` contains the entire match. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9UEDy/).

Comment: But you probably should subtract 1 from the month, as javascript counts from 0.

Comment: @alex: I tried this. But it is not showing error message on `00/00/0000`. But it is showing error when I use wrong format for example `00/0/00`. Thanks for your reply..

Comment: Pffft... My `.split('/').reverse().join('/')` is so much more elegant!  :)

Comment: @cwolves Hehe, yeah, but I saw what happened last time you thought I copied you ;)

Comment: hehehe, someone holds a grudge ;)

Comment: @alex: Oh I am confused. It is still accepting 00/00/0000 (Date with all zeros). It is showing error when I change the format but it is accepting correct format with all zeros digists(00/00/0000). I want to show same error when user use 00/00/0000. Or I am missing something ?? Anyway +1 for all for your efforts

Comment: @alex Whoops! I usually use `split()`. Didn't notice that you were using `match()`