# Validate mm/dd/yyyy with regEx

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, date

Its not working. I don't know regEx, but I need use it.

```
if ($('input[name="due_date"]').val().match("^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\\d\\d$")) {
  $('input[name="due_date"]').after("<span class='v_error'>Must fill</span>");
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about “not working”? Maybe you just need to insert `.value` in front of `.match`?

Comment: Can i ask why you need to use regex? This is better left to date and not regex. too many corner cases. Check this post out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511439/custom-date-format-with-jquery-validation-plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('input[name="due_date"]').val().match.......
```

Comment: No error msg, but when I add alert(), its alerting "Null" msg.

Comment: @Gerelt Od: Null means no match. Try alert($('input[name="due_date"]').val()).

Comment: val() working, its alerting input value. When I input correct value, its still alerting NULL.

Comment: Found it 8/24/2011 returning null. But 08/24/2011 returning value. How I modify my regEx for work first case?

Comment: Try `"^(0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\\d\\d$"`

Comment: @GereltOd let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2795/discussion-between-xdazz-and-gerelt-od)

Comment: Changed double slashes into single slashes at end of regEx. "^(0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$" Working well :) Thanks million times.

Answer (score 2):

A regex is surrounded with slashes. I just found that your regex is incorrect, too... So, coupled with the jQuery error pointed out by xdazz:

```
$('input[name="due_date"]').val().match(/^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$/);
```

The regex is from [this website](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html).

Comment: Its working, but now I need new regEx. I need regEx that works both 03/03/2011 and 3/3/2011 cases. If thats not possible at least I need regEx that works 3/3/2011 case.

Comment: of course it's possible...but it seems you already got your question answered.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to match with the HTML object, you might add .val() after the jQuery Selector, like

```
$('input[name="due_date"]').val().match(/^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\\d\\d$/);
```

Comment: I forgot, but, you don't have to put the regex betweens quotes (") check my code again, I edited it.