# jQuery validation - How to not accept a file extension

Tags: jquery, file, validation, jquery-validate

I would like to find a way to refuse a specific extension in a text field at form submission.

I have a field where you can specify a URL but this URL shouldn't link to a PDF file.

I figured that there is a jQuery validation methods called [`accept`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/accept#extension) that does exactly the contrary of what I want to do.

Is there a way to use with a `not()` function or something similar? It would be way easier than creating a custom validation method.

Comment: may be you have to create a custom rule for this validation. Check SO link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970434/several-custom-validate-rules-in-jquery-validate-plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is any idea

```
var ext = $('#fieldid').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
if($.inArray(ext, ['gif','jpg', ...]) == -1) {
    alert('invalid extension!');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Starx. I'll try to implement something like that pretty soon.