# validate selected date in selected month and year in dropdowns in client side

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with my mvc 4 application.Here I have Day ,Month ,Year dropdowns to select a date of birth. Now I want to validate a selected date in a selected month and year (especially February 29,28 , and for all month). Is there any defined jquery or javascript functions for that?

Please help.

Comment: did you try jquery validate plugin.

Comment: I need a method to validate these dropdowns or  rebindings based on month/year selection.

Comment: Did you try constructing a date from the dropdown values so that you can validate the date. Also did read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511439/custom-date-format-with-jquery-validation-plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function isDate(txtDate) {
    var currVal = txtDate;
    if (currVal == '')
       return false;

  //Declare Regex  
  var rxDatePattern = /^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{4})$/;
  var dtArray = currVal.match(rxDatePattern); // is format OK?

  if (dtArray == null)
      return false;

   //Checks for dd/mm/yyyy format.
   var dtDay = dtArray[1];
   var dtMonth = dtArray[3];
   var dtYear = dtArray[5];

  if (dtMonth < 1 || dtMonth > 12)
      return false;
  else if (dtDay < 1 || dtDay > 31)
      return false;
  else if ((dtMonth == 4 || dtMonth == 6 || dtMonth == 9 || dtMonth == 11) && dtDay == 31)
      return false;
  else if (dtMonth == 2) {
      var isleap = (dtYear % 4 == 0 && (dtYear % 100 != 0 || dtYear % 400 == 0));
      if (dtDay > 29 || (dtDay == 29 && !isleap))
          return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

This will work in this format "dd/MM/yyyy".

Comment: which jquery you are using...since i tested in http://jsfiddle.net/9mx7K/18/ its working fine for me

Comment: match is the basic method for javascript to validate the regular expression.

Comment: Thanks Anna, I have fixed the error and the solution works fine for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function checkdate(input){

var validformat=/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/ //Basic check for format validity
var returnval=false
if (!validformat.test(input.value))
alert("Invalid Date Format. Please correct and submit again.")
else{ 

var monthfield=input.value.split("/")[0]
var dayfield=input.value.split("/")[1]
var yearfield=input.value.split("/")[2]
var dayobj = new Date(yearfield, monthfield-1, dayfield)
if ((dayobj.getMonth()+1!=monthfield)||(dayobj.getDate()!=dayfield)||(dayobj.getFullYear()!=yearfield))
alert("Invalid Day, Month, or Year range detected. Please correct and submit again.")
else
returnval=true
}
if (returnval==false) input.select()
return returnval
}

</script>
```

u call this function onClick of submit button and you have to pass the date in mm/dd/yyyy format to this function . it will validate all dates. if you are facing issue then plz reply me .

Comment: I have passed '02/28/2013' as the  function argument but shows validation message 'Invalid Date Format. Please correct and submit again'

Comment: My goal is to validate any invalid date on a month ( for eg: if I give '02/February/2013, then need to show 'Invalid date selected')