# jQuery client side validation for rails datetime select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to add client side validation for a `datetime_select` field in rails. The datetime_select field in rails has different dropdowns for selecting year, month, day and time where ids are in the format `start_date_1i`, `start_date_2i`, ... and so on. How to take values using these ids and converting them to jquery datetime object.

I'm using this tag in my application

```
<%= f.datetime_select :start_date, {:default => { :hour => 17, :minute => 00 }, :ampm => true, :minute_step => 30}, {:required => true, :class => "start-time"} %>
```

It gets converted to HTML format which is as follows

```
<select id="banner_date_begin_1i" class="start-time" required="required" name="banner[date_begin(1i)]">
<select id="banner_date_begin_2i" class="start-time" required="required" name="banner[date_begin(2i)]">
<select id="banner_date_begin_3i" class="start-time" required="required" name="banner[date_begin(3i)]">
—
<select id="banner_date_begin_4i" class="start-time" required="required" name="banner[date_begin(4i)]">
:
<select id="banner_date_begin_5i" class="start-time" required="required" name="banner[date_begin(5i)]">
```

Comment: This could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751977/validate-selected-date-in-selected-month-and-year-in-dropdowns-in-client-side?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTimePicker on text_field. Look on http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/