# Jquery Validation plugin validate date like 20/August/2013 Safari Bug?

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, safari, jquery-validate

i use  Jquery Validation plugin and validates an event date like

```
rules:{
       eventdate: 
       {
       required:true,   
       date: true
       }
     }
```

> date format is like  "23/August/2013" ('dd/MM/yy')

but the code fails on **Safari** , works better with Fx,chrome,opera...

> **is it a Safari  Bug or a   Jquery Validation plugin bug ?**

i know that Jquery Validation plugin supports custom validation like

```
$.validator.addMethod("customdateValidateRule", function(value, element) 
{  
_isvalidResult=****testfn()***;
return _isvalidResult;
}
```

i tried [Custom date format with jQuery validation plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511439/custom-date-format-with-jquery-validation-plugin)
but wouldn't helped  as its in `dd/mm/yyyy`  not for  `('dd/MM/yy')` ,but regex for "`23/August/2013"` that i don't know!

**Remarks**

**1)** I use Datepicker(JqueryUi) for selecting the date 
**2)** i am using Jquery Validation plugin (latest) it  will  validate a  lot  of date formats it also validates "23/August/2013" (i assume) but when i test it in Safari it shows invalid where shown "valid" in FX,Chrome,Opera..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said if you are using `JqueryUi Datepicker` u have 2 ways

1) As @hwnd said you have to edit the validator plugin 
**2) Just add my hack below and happy with it !**

```
    /*Override the validator's Date Validation with mine! */
    $.validator.methods.date=
    function(value, element) {  
    try{
    var _appleDates=$.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy",$.datepicker.parseDate("dd/MM/yy",value));
    return (!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(_appleDates).toString()));
    }catch(e){return false;};
    };
```

**then use as you said**

```
rules:{
       eventdate: 
       {
       required:true,   
       date: true
       }
     }
```

**Thank you Be happy !**

Comment: @7-isnotbad glad to help u

Answer (score 4):

The issue is because Safari does not handle the format properly. JQuery validation plugin tool is not able to validate this format (only happens in `Chrome` and `Safari`). To solve this, modify the validation plugin.

If you want it customized for `dd/mm/yy`, you could do.

```
$.validator.addMethod(
   "customdateValidateRule", 
   function(value, element) {
      return value.match(/^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2}$/);
   },
      "Input a date format of dd/mm/yy:"
);
```

And add the rule validation to your form.

```
$('#myformname')
   .validate({
       rules : {
        myDate : {
          customdateValidateRule : true
        }
       }
   });
```

If you want to add the test method instead, you should be able to do something like..

```
var isdate = function(value) {
    var isvalid = /^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2})?$/;   
    return isvalid.test(value);
} 

$.validator.addMethod(
   "customdateValidateRule",
   function(value, element) {
      return isdate(value);
   }
);
```

If you need the regular expression to validate `dd/mm/yyyy`, change it to..

```
/^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/
```

For validating your specifics of a date for `23/August/2013`, you have a couple of options here.

There short way:

```
/^\d{1,2}\/\b[a-zA-Z]+\/\d{4}$/
```

Regular expression explanation:

```
^              the beginning of the string
 \d{1,2}       digits (0-9) (between 1 and 2 times)
  \/           look for and match '/'
   \b          the boundary between a word char (\w)
    [a-zA-Z]+  any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z' (1 or more times)
  \/           look for and match '/'
  \d{4}        digits (0-9) (4 times)
$              before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

The long way (specific validation):

```
/^\d{1,2}\/\b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|
                May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sept?|September|
                Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)\/\d{4}$/
```

Regular expression explanation:

```
^                     the beginning of the string
 \d{1,2}              digits (0-9) (between 1 and 2 times)
  \/                  look for and match '/'
   \b                 the boundary between a word char (\w)
    (?:               group, but do not capture:
     Jan(?:uary)?|    'Jan', group but don't capture optional 'uary', OR
     Feb(?:ruary)?|   'Feb', group but don't capture optional 'ruary', OR
     Mar(?:ch)?|      'Mar', group but don't capture optional 'ch', OR
     Apr(?:il)?|      'Apr', group but don't capture optional 'il', OR
     May|             'May', OR
     Jun(?:e)?|       'Jun', group but don't capture optional 'e', OR
     Jul(?:y)?|       'Jul', group but don't capture optional 'y', OR
     Aug(?:ust)?|     'Aug', group but don't capture optional 'ust', OR
     Sept?|           'Sep', 't' optional, OR
     September|       'September', OR
     Oct(?:ober)?|    'Oct', group but don't capture optional 'ober', OR
     Nov(?:ember)?|   'Nov', group but don't capture optional 'ember', OR
     Dec(?:ember)?    'Dec', group but don't capture optional 'ember'
    )                 end of grouping
     \/               look for and match '/'
      \d{4}           digits (0-9) (4 times)
$                     before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```