# How can I validate in bootstrap that at least one checkbox is marked and pass this information to php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I'm using bootstrap and I created a form with 8 checkboxes. When user clicks "Submit" I want to verify if at least one checkbox is marked and if not - let user know with an error message below the checkbox group.
Also, I would like to verify if the date that he puts is correct with my default data-form: 23/09/2015 05:45 PM

This is my java-script validation code:

```
$('#myform').validate({// initialize the plugin
    errorElement: 'div',
    rules: {
        datetimepicker: {
            required: true,
            date: true
        },
        commercialText: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        terms: {
            required: true,
            maxlength: 2
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) { 
        var text = $("#customtext").val();
        var date = $("#datetimepicker").val();
        var stand = 2; 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'savedatanow.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                text: text,
                date: date,
                stand: stand

            },
            dataType:'text',
            success: function(response)
            {

                alert(response);
            }
        });
        //alert('outside ajax');
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('success').addClass('has-error');
    },
    success: function (element) {
        element.addClass('valid')
            .closest('.form-group').removeClass('error').addClass('has-success');
    }                   
});
```

I prepared the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5WMff/1316/ but I have a problem with marking the correct error messages in red. When user doesn't check that he accepts the terms there's a weird situation happening too (the whole text is marked in red, not only the error)... Can you help me with that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can name the checkbox array whatever makes sense (I used `number[]` as a generic example), then add your rules and/or messages as usual.

You can use custom errorPlacement rules to add messages where appropriate. There's a target div for the checkbox array that's places in your HTML (`<div id="checkboxGroup"></div>`).

See docs: [jQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate)

```js
$('#myform').validate({
  rules: {
    datetimepicker: {
      required: true,
      date: true
    },
    commercialText: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 5
    },
    terms: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 1
    },
    'number[]': {
      required: true,
      minlength: 1,
      maxlength: 2
    }
  },

  messages: {
    datetimepicker: {
      required: "Please enter a date."
    },
    commercialText: {
      required: "Please enter your message."
    },
    terms: {
      required: "Please agree to terms."
    },
    'audit[]': {
      required: "Please check at least 1 option.",
      minlength: "Please check at least {0} option."
    }
  },

  submitHandler: function(form) {
    var text = $("#customtext").val();
    var date = $("#datetimepicker").val();
    var stand = 2;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'savedatanow.php',
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        text: text,
        date: date,
        stand: stand

      },
      dataType: 'text',
      success: function(response) {

        alert(response);
      }
    });
    //alert('outside ajax');
  },

  highlight: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
  },
  unhighlight: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
  },

  errorClass: 'help-block',
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (element.parent('.form-group').length) {
      error.insertAfter(element.parent());
    } else {
      error.insertAfter(element.parent());
    }
    if (element.attr('name') == 'number[]') {
      error.insertAfter('#checkboxGroup');
    } else {
      error.appendTo(element.parent().next());
    }
  }

});
```

```css
#myform .has-error .help-block {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  color: #737373;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form role="form" id="myform">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>what is your number?</label>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input name="number[]" type="checkbox" value="">one</label>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input name="number[]" type="checkbox" value="">two</label>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input name="number[]" type="checkbox" value="">three</label>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input name="number[]" type="checkbox" value="">four</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input name="number[]" type="checkbox" value="">five</label>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input name="number[]" type="checkbox" value="">six</label>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input name="number[]" type="checkbox" value="">seven</label>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input name="number[]" type="checkbox" value="">eight</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="checkboxGroup"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="datetimepicker">When do you want to go?</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datetimepicker" name="datetimepicker" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>How long will it last?</label>
      <select class="form-control">
        <option>5 seconds</option>
        <option>10 seconds</option>
        <option>15 seconds</option>
        <option>20 seconds</option>
        <option>30 seconds</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="commercialText">Write a text that:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="commercialText" name="commercialText" placeholder="hello"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="terms" name="terms">I accept the terms</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Create custom validator for group of elements.

```
$.validator.addMethod( "at_least_one", function() {
    return $( "input[name='number[]']:checked" ).length;
}, 'Select at least one number' );
```

Add rule.

```
rules: {
    "number[]": "at_least_one",
    .....
```

Add name and value attributes to checkboxes, here is an example of how to creates an array of the selected values with square braces to the checkbox names. That way `$_POST['number']` will be an array of checked values.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="two" name="number[]">
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5WMff/1320/)

For dates you can use [jQuery Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) or [THIS SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511439/custom-date-format-with-jquery-validation-plugin) question, basically create another custom validation method.

Now, there is still some issues with error messages and bootstrap, 
I hope that someone else will help you with that.

Comment: Thanks. why is the select new number is added as a new checkbox?